# How to check if any other App is using VoiceProcessingIO AU (macOS)

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiounit

If a VOIP app is using VoiceProcessingIO AU, then other app (not use VoiceProcessingIO) will be suppressed to deliver it's sound.

Is there any kAudioProperty to get, for developer to check if current environment exists any app using VoiceProcessingIO ?